# Unable to click button in a layout which contains a scroll view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-button

I have made a layout which contains a toolbar for a header, a scroll view as the body and a few buttons as the footer but no matter what i do the onClick listeners will not fire for the buttons.

Here's my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.octalogic.rescuegsbb.ActiveRescueDetail">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

    android:theme="@style/MyToolbarStyle" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/postRescueRequest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/divider"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rescueFail"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/rescue_fail"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rescueSuccess"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/rescued"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rescue"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/rescue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</FrameLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/red">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Custom Location"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here's my java code snippet

```
Button rescueRequestButton = findViewById(R.id.rescue);
 rescueRequestButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Log.i("Click", "clicked");
    });
```

The button shows up on the screen but tapping on it won't fire the click listener.

Comment: Is that how your `OnClickListener` looks exactly? Or did you shorten it for the question?

Comment: @H.Brooks I used lambda expressions so its like that.

Comment: Oh I see, then ignore my answer.

Comment: All other buttons are working? did your app get a exception before reach clicklistener?

Comment: btw, ["FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view,"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Comment: @PedroHawk the other 2 buttons work

Comment: make a test and put the button inside the LinearLayout. See if it works, otherwise check if the clicklistener is reach, on debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `OnClickListener` to:

```
Button rescueRequestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rescue);
rescueRequestButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Click", "clicked");
        }
    });
```